# Dendrogram to a directed graph/tree

Tags: python, dataframe, tree, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am trying to convert a dendrogram into a graph/tree to perform calculations with its nodes, leaves and subtrees and find a miximal subgraphs, but I have not found a function/package that helps me in this process

i was trying to convert the dendogram to a 'newick' format, but im not sure if it is the better way.

I created the dendogram with 'scipy.cluster.hierarchy' pakege

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Witht the **.to_tree** function you can convert the linkage matrix returned as Z in your code to a tree object.

```
tree_Z = hierarchy.to_tree(Z)
```

This gives you an [ClusterNode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.ClusterNode.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.ClusterNode) Tree object which you can traverse.